# SQL составной Primary key и Foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Имеется БД с двумя таблицами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно установить аттрибуты в 1 таблице

То есть если на 1 документ приходится скажем 3 Authors и 2 Keywords
То это должно выглядеть как

```
Document_id | index | Authors  | Keywords
        1   |     1 | BlaaBla  | Blabla
        1   |     2 | BlaaBla1 | Blabla1
        1   |     3 | BlaaBla2 | null
```

Как это реализовать правильно?

Comment: Да как нужно, так и реализуй. Это определяется собственно логикой процесса, а не программой реализацией.

Comment: так как на вашей картинке и нужно реализовать - первичный ключ может быть составным, а остальное у вас всё стандартное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE document_r
(
    document_id int NOT NULL,
    index int NOT NULL,
    authors varchar(255),
    keywords varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (document_id,index), 
    FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES document_s(document_id)    
)
```

Comment: А индекс должен получается инкрементиться на каждый id заново или это не обязательно?

Comment: комбинация document_id + index должна быть уникальной в таблице, как этого добьетесь базе данных все равно, 2 записи с одинаковым первичным ключом она просто не вставит

Comment: Благодарю за ясный ответ

Comment: на автоинкремент полей можно создавать sequence - посмотрите синтаксис в доке, или тут пример https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm

Comment: появился один нюанс мне необходимо чтобы значения index были в определенном диапазоне, то есть на 1 id приходится 2 автора и 3 keyworda  то количество записей должно быть MAX [2,3] = 3 то есть индексы на 1 id Должны Быть 1, 2, 3

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm

Comment: но это не совсем то что я имею ввиду это что то скорее типа вот этого https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html  MyISAM Notes